# What is needed to secure a docker container that's running on nodes in an AWS Private Subnet with internet access only via NAT?

Tags: aws, docker

I know securing a container is a big deal and a lot is needed to be done to secure a default container configuration. But having it in a private subnet should take care of a lots of risks.

So what major things does one need to start with to secure a docker container that's running on nodes in an AWS Private Subnet with internet access only via NAT?

Comment: Security should be implemented in layers, so that the result of one misconfiguration, or bug doesn't completely compromise a system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The security configuration required for a specific environment depends on your threat model e.g. who do you expect to attack you, what level of access will they have to your environment, so providing specific hardening instructions for Docker containers could be hard without that detail.

At a generic level I'd recommend reviewing the [CIS Benchmark for Docker](https://www.cisecurity.org/benchmark/docker/)  to see which of the recommendations there make sense for your environment.